# how indexing works internally in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

An Index is nothing but a pointer on a particular column of a table. Creating an index means creating a pointer on a particular column of a table. If a column is indexed in a table, and how the data of that particular column is pointed,when that specific column is queried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation

> The goal of Hive indexing is to improve the speed of query lookup on
>   certain columns of a table. Without an index, queries with predicates
>   like 'WHERE tab1.col1 = 10' load the entire table or partition and
>   process all the rows. But if an index exists for col1, then only a
>   portion of the file needs to be loaded and processed. The improvement
>   in query speed that an index can provide comes at the cost of
>   additional processing to create the index and disk space to store the
>   index.

Behind the scene, Hive creates essentially a  Map with the values of the column that it is indexing and the offset + files where the data is located in the HDFS, in that way, Hive does not need to scan all the data to search for a certain value.  Here is a good article explaining basic concepts

https://acadgild.com/blog/indexing-in-hive/